# Elasticsearch join-like query within same index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a following structure (mapping)

```
{
    "properties": {
        "content": {
            "type": "text",
        },
        "prev_id": {
            "type": "text",
        },
        "next_id": {
            "type": "text",
        }
    }
}
```

where `prev_id` and `next_id` are IDs of documents in this index (may be `null` values).

I want to perform `_search` query and get `prev.content` and `next.content` fields.

Now I use two queries: the first for searching by `content` field

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/idx/_search'  -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "yellow fox"
    }
  }
}'
```

and the second to get `next` and `prev` records.

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/idx/_search'  -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values" : ["5bb93552e42140f955501d7b77dc8a0a", "cd027a48445a0a193bc80982748bc846", "9a5b7359d3081f10d099db87c3226d82"]
    }
  }
}'
```

Then I join results on application-side.

Can I achieve my goal with one query only?

PS: the purpose to store `next-prev` as IDs is to safe disk space. I have a lot of records and `content` field is quite large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is the way to go. But how large is the content? - Maybe you can consider not storing content ( source = false)?

Comment: Thank you. `source=false` definitely helps to save even more space!